# n points sampled uniformly from $[-1,1]^2$, how many lie within the unit circle?

Tags: expected-value

I was looking at the expected output of an algorithm and translated it into this equivalent problem:

> Consider $n$ points sampled uniformly from $[-1,1]^2$ and let $A=\frac{4Z}{n}$ where $Z$ is how many of these $n$ points lie within the interior and boundary of the unit circle. Find $\mathbb{E}[A]$.

I tried running the algorithm but I fail to recognize if the output value is approximating a familiar number. How does one compute for this expected value?

Answer (score 0):

- The probability that a single point lies in the unit circle is $p := \frac{\text{area of unit circle}}{\text{area of $[-1,1]^2$}}$.
- $E[Z] = np$ (why?)
- $E[A] = \frac{4}{n} E[Z]$ (why?)